# Autofill Application.Countifs.Formula VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I think this might be a simple question but I can't seem to find a way to autofill an Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIf formula so that the row number would change as the formula goes down.

I want to autofill this formula for B2 till LastRow from Column A
`Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(**B2 Here**), Doctors, Sheet2.Range(**B2 Here**), wsf.Transpose(Emergency)))`

So lets assume that the last used row for column A is 6, so the formula should autofill from B2 until B6 such as:

B3 = `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(**B3 Here**)....`

B4 = `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(**B4 Here**)....`

B5 = `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(**B5 Here**)....`

B6 = `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(**B6 Here**)....`

I don't want to use .Formula "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS....." approach so that I can use arrays as the criteria vary according to the selected dropdown choices.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

`AutoFill` can do this for you. Assuming your formula begins in `B2` and the end row changes, the syntax would be:

```
LRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("B2")
    .Formula = 'Your formula here.
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & LRow)
End With
```

Another option would be using `FillDown` as `AutoFill` almost always have quirks. The syntax is pretty much the same:

```
LRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula = 'Your formula here.
Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & LRow).FillDown
```

Let us know if this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Much like Dave's answer, here's my take on your formula:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as required.

    With Sh
        LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp.Row)
        .Range("B2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16, ""Doctors"", $I$2:$I$16, $B2))"
        .Range("B2:B" & LRow).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

**HOWEVER**, here's the clincher: If you are merely doing a `COUNTIFS` checking if `Column C` has `Doctors` as value and `Column I` has the value of `B2`, you should remove the `SUMPRODUCT` from your formula as it's not necessary. `SUMPRODUCT` was once the way to check multiple conditions, but in Excel 2007 and up, it's been completely replaced by `COUNTIFS` for simple multiple condition-based check-and-count. What I'm saying is, the proper code is pretty much the following:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as required.

    With Sh
        LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp.Row)
        .Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16, ""Doctors"", $I$2:$I$16, $B2)"
        .Range("B2:B" & LRow).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

**STILL**, further formula forensics and evaluation reveal a trickier part: You are entering your formula in `B2` and below, but your `COUNTIFS` is checking `B2` and below as part of the condition as well. This is not only confusing but is also prone to error (if not already erroneous) as it will result into a circular reference.

At this point, my question now is, what exactly are you trying to check and/or count? This is more than just a VBA issue, in my opinion, as I believe that you are confused as to what and how you want to get your numbers. While our approach is sound and is basically perfect for your question, if the formula is incorrect, the above is useless. :)

Comment: Nice one! You can probably remove `Columns("A")`, as column "A" is also referenced in `Cells(Rows.Count,1)` - eg `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Hey, Dave. Changed as per your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried this code: `Dim wsf
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
LRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula = "Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet1.Range(""C2:C16""), Doctors, Sheet1.Range(""I2:I16""), Sheet1.Range(""B2"")))"
Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & LRow).FillDown` It is not working I want B2 to change as the formula is filled down. What am I doing wrong? @DaveU Any Clues?

Comment: `Application.Worksheet...` is not used inside a cell. If you use the `.Formula` property, the formula you want should be as it should have been had you entered it to the cell properly. Also, you cannot `Dim` a function. `Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction` is not a valid declaration. See my modified answer above.

Comment: @BK201, I find it interesting that someone else also finds the formula somewhat confusing.  Question - I noticed that you removed the sheet references (`.Name`) from the formula text.  Is it because we're assuming the formula is operating on the active sheet in this scenario?  Just asking;-)

Comment: @DaveU: You're correct. :) The above was actually tested with dummy data that mirrors the OP's data somewhat, which is why I did not bother using `.Name` for the time being. I was actually too concentrated on the VBA that I noticed the formula a little too late. It worked, but it prompted a circular reference, which I was apparently too careless to notice the first time around. Because of this, I decided to just investigate the formula and not the VBA, as our approaches have been perfect for the request anyway. ;)

Comment: @DaveU Thanks for the above answer. However Doctors is actually a defined array: `Doctors = Array("John", "Peter", "Tom")` Unfortunately when using the above it treats "Doctors" as a criteria rather than an array. Any way to fix that without merging {"John", "Peter", "Tom"} into the formula as the Doctor array changes based on a Dropdown control. Thanks.

Comment: @BK201 Any suggestions for the above comment?

Comment: You'll need to get the dropdown value into a string, and substitute that into the formula, instead of "Doctors"

Comment: @DaveU Thank you for the prompt response. How do I need to go about getting the value into a string and substitute it? And will it work when for example the Dropdown value is "All" and the Doctors need to be "John" and "Peter" and "Tom"

Comment: What sort of dropdown is it, a validation cell, or a form control (combo box)?  If it's a validation cell, then s=cell.value, and substitute "s" for "Doctors" in the formula.  To use "All" will require a bit more effort, but possible

Comment: @DaveU It's a combobox. My main problem is using the "All" criteria. Also, when I try to substitute anything in place of "Doctors" it gives me 0 results. Any clues?

Comment: I'm actually having a problem getting your formula to work `.Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16, ""Doctors"" , $I$2:$I$16, $B2)"` Your 2nd criteria is the result of the formula, so I think `$B2` should be something else.  Not an expert on COUNTIFS, maybe @BK201 has some advice.

Comment: @DaveU I have actually changed the formula so that `$B2` is now `$A2`. But I still am having trouble to define the "Doctors" part and get it to work,

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't post some code right now. However, form controls are linked to a cell, are they not? If so, it's a matter of an `IF THEN` where if combo box is equal to All, condition is equal to a wildcard to catch all the doctors' names. Or am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Here's how my data is laid out:

[image]

This code goes in regular module:

```
Sub Test(s As String) 'input frpm combo box
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, LRow As Long
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as required.
    If LCase(s) = "all" Then s = "*"
    s = Chr(34) & s & Chr(34) 'bracket with quotes
    With Sh
        LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$16," & s & ", $I$2:$I$16, $A2)"
        .Range("B2:B" & LRow).FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

This code goes in sheet module of combo box (Sheet1 in this instance).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Test Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

I'm not sure of your formula results, but it is getting loaded correctly.

Comment: I've modified the code to incorporate `All`- @BK201, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you're satisfied, could you check this question as answered, thanks.